# How to remove a html element using :not and jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use the following code:

```
$(':not(.fc-event.active-wrapper) .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
```

I assumed that this would remove all elements with an 'outer-event-info-wrapper' class, which do NOT have a parent of .fc-event.active-wrapper. What looks like is happening is that ALL elements with 'outer-event-info-wrapper' class are being removed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is my whole script:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                console.log($(this).find('.outer-event-info-wrapper'));
                //$(this).find('.outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
                $('.active-event').removeClass('active-event')
                $(this).addClass('active-event');
                if(!$(this).hasClass('active-event')) {

                }
                //$('.outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
                $('.outer-event-info-wrapper').not('.fc-event.active-wrapper .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log(url);
                var $this = $(this);
                var $thisHtml = $this.html();
                $.get('calendar/event/teaser',{url: url},function(data, status) {
                        if(status) {
                            $this.html($thisHtml + data);
                        }
                    },
                    'html'
                );
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Consider that the `html`, `body`, and any other ancestor elements probably don't have the `.fc-event.active-wrapper` class, and therefor match the first part of the selector.

Comment: `$('.outer-event-info-wrapper').not('.fc-event.active-wrapper .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();`

Comment: That is true, but since they don't match the second part, they wont be selected, right?

Comment: How about his : $(".fc-event.active-wrapper").has(".outer-event-info-wrapper").remove()

Comment: @user1015214, I think you're misunderstanding how selectors work. Any `.outer-event-info-wrapper` within `body` will be selected by the selector you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You could select all `.outer-event-info-wrapper` then filter out `.fc-event.active-wrapper .outer-event-info-wrapper` elements like

```
$('.outer-event-info-wrapper').not('.fc-event.active-wrapper .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
```

```js
$('.outer-event-info-wrapper').not('.fc-event.active-wrapper .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fc-event active-wrapper">
  <span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">1</span>
  <span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">2</span>
  <span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">3</span>
</div>

<span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">4</span>
<span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">5</span>
<span class="outer-event-info-wrapper">6</span>
```

Your selector won't work if there is at least one ancestor which do not have the class `fc-event.active-wrapper`, which there will be like `html`, `body` etc

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Would this work even if I added the class via javascript ie: .addClass('active-class')?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `>` between your two selectors to express the parent-child relationship. At the moment with just a space separator you're specifying an ancestor-descendant relationship, and all your `.outer-event-info-wrapper` elements are descendants of at least one `not .fc-event.active-wrapper` ancestor.

```
$(':not(.fc-event.active-wrapper) > .outer-event-info-wrapper').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single selector string (such as when passing a selector as an option to a plugin) you can use a format like:

```
'.outer-event-info-wrapper:not(.fc-event.active-wrapper *)'
```

The general form is:

```
'<selector to match>:not(<parent to exclude> *)'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
$(".fc-event.active-wrapper").has(".outer-event-info-wrapper").remove()
```